# Github support of Semver patterns

Tags: regex, github, tags, semantic-versioning

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to set up a deployment environment tag rule in Github with the recommended Semver regex pattern on the bottom of page here: https://semver.org/

Issue I am encountering:

The Semver pattern I use is 180 characters long. Github rule allows only 100 characters, so it truncates the tail of the pattern.

I reduced the length to 87, with no luck. Eventually, I left only the core major.minor.patch portion, which still didn't work for another reason.

Original
^(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$

Attempt 2
^(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))

Attempt 3
^(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*).(0|[1-9]\d*)

Is there any way to set the pattern another way or is shortening it the only solution?

Comment: No idea what the issue is, but doesn't attempt 3 prove your issue isn't one of char length?

Comment: I would say the opposite: Github has a length limitation that prevents the use of patterns longer than 100 characters and also doesn't seem to work well with the SemVer patterns for other reasons.

https://regex101.com/r/5lUsPh/1

I found an answer here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules#adding-tag-protection-rules

GitHub actually uses fnmatch for pattern matching, not a regular Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Github uses fnmatch for the Tag Rules, not regular Regex pattern.

More here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-tag-protection-rules#adding-tag-protection-rules